# Query using ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just started using Android and Firebase. I have built a simple test Firebase database and I want to run a simple query.

If I use `ChildEventListener`, I get reasonable results and code for that looks like this:-

```
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("calendarGroup").equalTo("2");

    mChildEventListner = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            CalendarEntry calendarEntry = dataSnapshot.getValue(CalendarEntry.class);
            linesToDisplay = linesToDisplay + "\n" + calendarEntry.getCalendarDate() +
                    ", " + calendarEntry.getCalendarEntry() +
                    ", " + calendarEntry.getCalendarGroup();
            resultText.setText(linesToDisplay);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.show();
            ;
        }
    };

    query.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListner);
```

But as this is a single event query, I wanted to do that using `SingleValueListener`. It doesn't work (I get null values), The code is below:-

```
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("calendarGroup").equalTo("2");

    ValueEventListener mValueEventListener;

    mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            CalendarEntry calendarEntry = dataSnapshot.getValue(CalendarEntry.class);
            linesToDisplay = linesToDisplay + "\n" + calendarEntry.getCalendarDate() +
                    ", " + calendarEntry.getCalendarEntry() +
                    ", " + calendarEntry.getCalendarGroup();
            resultText.setText(linesToDisplay);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
        }


    };

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(mValueEventListener);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in what part of your activity do you add these code parts?

Comment: I am using it from OnClickListener for a button that is created in OnCreate of the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do this:

```
mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        CalendarEntry calendarEntry = data.getValue(CalendarEntry.class);
        linesToDisplay = linesToDisplay + "\n" + calendarEntry.getCalendarDate() +
                ", " + calendarEntry.getCalendarEntry() +
                ", " + calendarEntry.getCalendarGroup();
        resultText.setText(linesToDisplay);

    }
  }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
    }


};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(mValueEventListener);
```

Please add the `for` loop to be able to retrieve the data.

In `ValueEventListener` you have to loop inside the node which is different that the `childeventlistener` where it is able to get the values without looping.